# How to deploy AWS python Lambda project locally?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, deployment, aws-lambda, chalice

I got an AWS python Lambda function which contains few python files and also several dependencies.

The app is build using `Chalice` so by that the function will be mapped like any REST function.

Before the deployment in prod env, I want to test it locally, so I need to pack all this project (python files and dependencies), I tried to look over the web for the desired solution but I couldn't find it.

I managed to figrue how to deploy one python file, but a whole project did not succeed.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to the Atlassian's Localstack: https://github.com/atlassian/localstack

It's a full copy of the AWS cloud stack, locally.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Travis](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/getting-started/) : I hooked it to my master branch in git, so that when I push on this branch, Travis tests my lambda, with a script that uses `pytest`, after having installed all its dependencies with `pip install`. If all the tests passed, it then deploy the lambda in AWS in my prod-env.